# Nuget package build for class library

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Which field in VS project settings -> Package provides the file name when a package is built from a class library?

I've tried the following fields and none of them seem to do it: Package ID, Title, Product

The only thing I haven't tried is specifiying an Output Path including the file name. In the following examples, I would like it to be called Globalization.nupkg (where .nupkg is the file type). I want to drop the version number.

[image: nuget packages]

Comment: You can take a look at my answer. It should work. But please notice that a really no-version package is impossible. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like it to be called Globalization.nupkg (where .nupkg is the
> file type). I want to drop the version number.

First of all, it must be emphasized that if you want a truly "unversioned" nuget package, **this is definitely not possible.** The package version is a value that must be provided to create a package, which is unavoidable.

You can see the required properties of the package here:

[General form and schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#general-form-and-schema)

When you use the GeneratePackageOnBuild property and set it as true, the project will generate a package during the build. If the required properties were not be given, it will use the default value.

That means the metadata containing version info is unavoidable in nuget package.

---

## But if you just want to change the generated nuget package name, it is possible.

You can use build event:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <PackageId>Globalization</PackageId>
        <PackageVersion>1.0.0</PackageVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="Pack">
        <Exec Command="move /Y bin\Debug\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg bin\Debug\$(PackageId).nupkg" />
        <!--This is the key part.-->
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Result:

[image]